# Connecting to .NET COM app from .NET COM client

Tags: .net, com, com-interop

I'm having trouble with something that should be brain-dead simple.

I am writing a COM client in .NET that will eventually talk to an old-style C++ COM interface when the server code is written. In the meantime, I've written an unsigned WPF .NET application and implemented the same interface - same IID, different ProgID and CLSID - so I'll have a harness I can test with. In theory, all I will need to do is switch my reference from one namespace to another and change the concrete class on the **new** statement and everything else will remain the same. I'm envisioning that when I CoCreate the CLSID, it will bring up the application with its GUI and my client can do its calls OLE Automation-style from there and see the effects on the screen.

Only that's not what's happening. In Add References for my client application, I see the typelib for my test harness in the COM list, but it refuses to let me add the reference because it detects that it is a .NET type library and expects a .NET reference. If I reference it as a project or browse to it as an EXE, it apparently loads the EXE in-process as if it were a DLL and uses the COM classes without actually activating it out of process.

I figured anything I did with a .NET COM application would work similarly to a C++ COM application. I'm not sure what my options are at this point. Am I facing a hard limitation or are there [attributes] that affect this behavior? (It has admittedly been a couple of years since I did really seriously detailed COM interop and I have an uneasy feeling that this is something really simple that I've since forgotten.)

Lupestro

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you need is out-of-proc COM object. You can create COM+ objects inplemented in .Net and then instantiate them out-of-proc. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973847.aspx) explains how to do that.